# AudioKit AKSequencer + AKAudioUnitManager

Tags: ios, audiokit

I’m trying to figure out how to play midi sequence from AKSequencer in AUv3 synthesizer.

Official example of AKAudioUnitManager only shows how to load instruments/effects but it lucks a midi sending examples. Or I missed them :)

Can somebody provide an example how to connect midi-output of sequencer to audio unit?

Thanks!